# Multiple selectors for jQuery on method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to pass more than one child selectors in the jQuery on method?

```
$("#tablename").on("click", "tr", function() {
}
```

click needs to be fired if the user click on tr or checkbox. Something like:

```
$("#tablename").on("click", "tr input[type='checkbox']", function() {
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Yes, it will work absolutely fine.

Comment: And why would a checkbox inside a table be anywhere but inside a TR ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to specify more than one selector

```
$("#tablename").on("click", "tr, input[type='checkbox']", function() {
});
```

But in a table all elements could be in a `tr` so what is the difference

Comment: Thanks for your help, i missed the comma between the selectors.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine them with comma using [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), the closing parenthesis is also missing. If you have space instead of comma it is treated as [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/).

```
$("#tablename").on("click", "tr, input[type='checkbox']", function() {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  comma `,` for multiple selector

```
   $("#tablename").on("click", "tr, input[type='checkbox']", function() {
                    //use "," ---^^^---- here for multiple 
    });
```

reference **[multiple-selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)**

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, your code works fine. But the problem is the event will be fired twice if the check box is inside the 'tr'. To prevent it you have to force the event delegation. You receive the event as a argument and in your code use e.preventDefault(). This will make sure click event is not delegated from checkbox to parent 'tr'.

```
$("#tablename").on("click", "tr, input[type='checkbox']", function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault(); // This is wrong, plz check
    e.stopPropagation(); // Hope this will help you one day
});
```